# loading animation not showing

Tags: javascript, css

When I click on the button, I see the alert, but during the `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));` I don't see the loading animation.

```js
/* script.js */

async function refreshStatus() {
  document.getElementById("loading-overlay").display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("loader").display = "block";
  alert("trying");

  try {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    var response = await fetch(
      the_url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({"ok": "yes"})
      }
    );
  }
  catch (_error) {
    document.getElementById("error-div").display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("error-div").innerHTML = _error.message;
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
/* loading.css */

#loading-overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#error-div {
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- <link href="loading.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->

  <!-- <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" /> -->
</head>
    
<body>
  <div id="loading-overlay">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <p id="error-div"></p>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="button_queue_go" onclick="refreshStatus();">Show Status</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Few things were missed in your code that prevented the 'loading' circle from being shown:

- In your HTML code, to change display of an HTML div from JS you need to access it thru .style.display and not .display. Thus, your HTML should be - see below.
- In your loading.css you were missing to access the loader by: #loader and not .loader since loader is an id in the HTML

```css
#loading-overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}
#loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#error-div {
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="loading.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            async function refreshStatus()
            {
                document.getElementById("loading-overlay").style.display = "flex";
                document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
                alert("trying");
                try
                {
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
                    var response = await fetch(
                        the_url,
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                                    },
                            body: JSON.stringify({"ok": "yes"})
                        }
                    );
                }
                catch (_error)
                {
                    document.getElementById("error-div").style.display = "flex";
                    document.getElementById("error-div").innerHTML = _error.message;
                    return;
                }
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="loading-overlay">
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <p id="error-div"></p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="button_queue_go" onclick="refreshStatus();">Show Status</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but the spinner is not spinning. Also its showing up on top left corner and does not go after the catch block is executed.

Comment: Your original code didnt show the spinner at all becuase of the above issues. Now, the pircture appears (static, right)...
To make it dynamic and spin you need to deal with css ..which I think different story...
There are lot of places showing that...for instance, see the [How to Create Loading Spinner With CSS](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-create-loading-spinner-with-css.html)